# legendrank in R plotly - bug or user error?

Tags: r, plotly, legend

I encountered unwanted behaviour using plotly (4.10.1) in R with regards to the order that legends appear.
I have raised a formal `issue` at https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/2233 ; however I accept that there may be misunderstanding or 'user error' on my part. If someone can demonstrate that here, I will clean house and remove my bug report.

Here is the reprex.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
(tot_df <- structure(list(
  rank = structure(c(
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
  ), levels = c(
    "1", "2", "3",
    "4"
  ), class = "factor"), value = c(
    1, 0.316227766016838, 2, 0.447213595499958,
    3, 0.547722557505166, 4, 0.632455532033676, 5, 0.707106781186548,
    3, 0.547722557505166, 2, 0.447213595499958, 1, 0.316227766016838
  ), name = c(
    "stat1", "stat_2", "stat1", "stat_2", "stat1", "stat_2",
    "stat1", "stat_2", "stat1", "stat_2", "stat1", "stat_2", "stat1",
    "stat_2", "stat1", "stat_2"
  ), `Display name` = structure(c(
    1L,
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
  ), levels = c(
    "Reference",
    "Current"
  ), class = "factor"), series_name_text = structure(c(
    1L,
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
  ), levels = c(
    "Reference stat1",
    "Reference stat_2", "Current stat1", "Current stat_2"
  ), class = "factor"),
  my_legend_rank = c(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L,
    3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
  )
), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
))
)


px <- plot_ly(
  data = tot_df,
  width = 800,
  height = 600,
  x = ~rank,
  y = ~value,
  name = ~series_name_text,
  legendrank = ~my_legend_rank,
  color = ~`Display name`,
  colors = c("green", "blue"),
  textposition = "none",
  type = "bar",
  opacity = .5,
  yaxis = "y"
) |> layout(legend = list(
  orientation = "h",
  xanchor = "center",
  yanchor = "bottom",
  y = -0.3,
  x = 0.5
))

# table(tot_df$series_name_text,tot_df$my_legend_rank
#                  1 2 3 4
# Reference stat1  4 0 0 0
# Reference stat_2 0 4 0 0
# Current stat1    0 0 4 0
# Current stat_2   0 0 0 4
```

visually we can see this is not honoured.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm reproducing the additional info I provided to the issues tracker .
https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/2233#issuecomment-1422537826
I have done additionally analysis; and show the origin of the problem; and how I solve / hacked around the issue. but I believe this should be best addressed by plotly internals, or by improving the documentation ?

```
pb_repair <- plotly_build(px)

 pb_repair$x$data[[1]]$legendrank
#[1] 1 2 3 4
pb_repair$x$data[[1]]$name
#[1] Current stat1
# 4 Levels: Reference stat1 ... Current stat_2
```

This is surely not intended; eachname should have a single associated legendrank and not the full list of all legendranks ?

```
# forcing solution - 
(to_do <- length(pb_repair$x$data))

for(i in seq_len(to_do)){
  pb_repair$x$data[[i]]$legendrank <- as.integer(pb_repair$x$data[[i]]$name)
}

pb_repair
```

[image]

As can be seen in this image. now reference stat1 is indeed the first/leftmost

I consider this an ugly hack ; but it will have to do until the plotly developers respond...